# Lagrange multiplier for sum of products with sum constraint

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Is it possible to use Lagrange multipliers (or another technique) to easily find a maximum of a function like
$$
f:
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R}^3_{\ge0}&\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\\
(x_1,x_2,x_3)&\mapsto x_1x_2x_3+ 2x_1x_2+3x_1x_3+x_2
\end{cases}
$$ with the constraint that the sum of the arguments $\sum_{i=1}^3x_i=s$ for some $s\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. I know that  the product $x_1x_2x_3$ is maximized when all variables are the same but here, we have a weighted sum of partial products. (The function is given only as an example, I actually want to find a maximum of a function with more variables but of the same kind, i.e. weighted sum of partial products where each variable has either power 0 or 1 in the exponent)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to solve this constrained optimization problem using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @molarmass Can you please indicate how? Setting the differential of the Lagrangian to zero gives a non-linear problem where I do not see how it can be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Lagrange's Multipliers technique the formulation could be

Given

$$
f(x) = x_1 x_2 x_3 +2x_2 x_2+3x_1 x_3+x_2\\
g_1(x) = x_1+x_2+x_3 - s = 0\\
g_2(x,\epsilon) = x_1 - \epsilon_1^2 = 0\\
g_3(x,\epsilon) = x_2 - \epsilon_2^2 = 0\\
g_4(x,\epsilon) = x_3 - \epsilon_3^2 = 0\\
$$

Determine the stationary points for

$$
L(x,\lambda,\epsilon) = f(x)+\lambda _1g_1(x)+\sum_{k=1}^3\lambda_{k+1}g_{k+1}(x_k,\epsilon_k)
$$

Here $\lambda_k$ are the so called Lagrange multipliers and $\epsilon_k$ are slack variables to transform the restrictions $x_k \ge 0$ into equivalent equality restrictions.

Now the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \lambda_1+\lambda_2+2 x_2+x_2x_3+3 z=0 \\
 \lambda_1+\lambda_3+2 x_1+x_1 x_3+1=0 \\
 \lambda_1+\lambda_4+3 x_1+x_1 x_2=0 \\
 x_1+x_2+x_3-s=0 \\
 x_1-\epsilon_1^2=0 \\
 x_2-\epsilon_2^2=0 \\
 x_3-\epsilon_3^2=0 \\
 -2 \epsilon_1 \lambda_2=0 \\
 -2 \epsilon_2 \lambda_3=0 \\
 -2 \epsilon_3 \lambda_4=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

After that, the solutions should be qualified as local minimum, local maximum or saddle point. This is done with the Hessian from

$$
(f\circ g_1)(x) = f(x_1,x_2,s-x_1-x_2)
$$

NOTE

For $s = 2$ we have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
x_1 & x_ 2 & x_3 & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 & \epsilon_1 & \epsilon_2 & \epsilon_3 & f(x)\\
 0 & 0 & 2. & 0 & -6. & -1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1.41421 & 0. \\
 0 & 0 & 2. & 0 & -6. & -1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.41421 & 0. \\
 0 & 2. & 0 & -1. & -3. & 0 & 1. & 0 & -1.41421 & 0 & 2. \\
 0 & 2. & 0 & -1. & -3. & 0 & 1. & 0 & 1.41421 & 0 & 2. \\
 0.75 & 1.25 & 0 & -2.5 & 0 & 0 & -0.6875 & -0.866025 & -1.11803 & 0 & 3.125 \\
 0.75 & 1.25 & 0 & -2.5 & 0 & 0 & -0.6875 & -0.866025 & 1.11803 & 0 & 3.125 \\
 0.75 & 1.25 & 0 & -2.5 & 0 & 0 & -0.6875 & 0.866025 & -1.11803 & 0 & 3.125 \\
 0.75 & 1.25 & 0 & -2.5 & 0 & 0 & -0.6875 & 0.866025 & 1.11803 & 0 & 3.125 \\
 1. & 0 & 1. & -3. & 0 & -1. & 0 & -1. & 0 & -1. & 3. \\
 1. & 0 & 1. & -3. & 0 & -1. & 0 & -1. & 0 & 1. & 3. \\
 1. & 0 & 1. & -3. & 0 & -1. & 0 & 1. & 0 & -1. & 3. \\
 1. & 0 & 1. & -3. & 0 & -1. & 0 & 1. & 0 & 1. & 3. \\
 2. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5. & -6. & -1.41421 & 0 & 0 & 0. \\
 2. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5. & -6. & 1.41421 & 0 & 0 & 0. \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The superabundant solutions are due to $\epsilon_k^2$

A solution with $\epsilon_k = 0$ means that the restriction $g_{k+1}(x,\epsilon)$ is active.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you also explain how one determines these solutions (since one cannot use Linear Algebra)? Is there a software (i.e. NumPy) that can determine these solutions (since my setting is bigger)

Comment: Is it correct with in the definitions of $g_2,...,g_4$ without a square of the $\epsilon$ variables?

Comment: @phinz I use MATHEMATICA which handles well those equations. You can formulate also the problem without the slack $\epsilon_k$ I did this way to show one of the variants when handling inequality restrictions. The slack variables are convenient in more complicated situations. MATHEMATICA is especially useful in those simple problems.

Comment: @phinz Please  verify the corrections introduced in the definition of $g_2,\cdots, g_4$ The correct formulation is with $\epsilon_k^2$ as it is now.